# Banana Pi as mass storage device

Tags: linux, usb, usb-storage

Is it possible to let a `Banana Pi` act as USB Slave so others can access to it as if it would be a mass storage device (like a USB flash drive)?

The idea behind that is that I have a TV which only supports USB to play video files. I basically want to play a video file from by `Banana Pi` on my TV without copying it to another device first.

Comment: It's possible to use a SBC (such as the Banana Pi) as a USB mass storage device.  Typically the SBC has a USB OTG port with a USB micro-B (or mini-B connector).  So you would need a USB micro-B to type-A cable to connect to the TV.  But the bigger issue is software, and unless you can find it, then you'll have to write it.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, yes. BPi has a USB OTG port which should be fully functional. What works and how depends on the software. You'll need a kernel and DT with the right support and you need to set the right mode and the right gadget driver.

In case of storage, that should be something like

```
modprobe g_mass_storage file=/mnt/disk.img
```

I intend to try doing the same at some point, but haven't actually tried yet.

Some sources:

- https://linux-sunxi.org/USB_Gadget/Mass_storage
- https://forum.armbian.com/